# Time out an ActiveRecord query

Tags: activerecord, timeout

I would like to time out an ActiveRecord query using Timeout from Ruby core, however ActiveRecord seems to be catching the `Timeout::Error` and wrapping it in a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` exception.

```
> Timeout::timeout(3) { sleep 4000 }
Timeout::Error: execution expired
...

> Timeout::timeout(3) { ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "select pg_sleep(4)"}
(3001.5ms)  select pg_sleep(4)
: execution expired: select pg_sleep(4)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: : execution expired: select pg_sleep(4)
...
```

This is unfortunate as I would also like to catch real SQL errors generating `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` exceptions and treat them differently.
Is there a way to differentiate the two ? (cleaner than matching the exception message for "execution expired").

Comment: You have to actually look at the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```rb
begin  
  Timeout::timeout(3) do  
    begin  
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "select pg_sleep(4)"  
    rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid  
      # handle ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid exception  
    end
  end
rescue Timeout::Error  
  # handle Timeout::Error exception
end
```

If you want to recieve Timeout::Error you should catch all other exceptions in timeout block.

Comment: `Timeout::timeout` is deceptively simple but can lead to very unpredictable outcomes. These articles explain the kinds of bugs which can occur:
- https://jvns.ca/blog/2015/11/27/why-rubys-timeout-is-dangerous-and-thread-dot-raise-is-terrifying/
- http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/