# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Timeout::Error: execution expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have an application running on heroku  that, on occasion, reports Timeout::Error and (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Timeout::Error: execution expired) "execution expired".

This happens all over the website(not for any specific query).

Example -:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Timeout::Error: execution expired: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3881 LIMIT 1

My app is on rails 3.2.11

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Rack::Timeout? I've been struggling over the same issue and I think it's because my code is timing out from Rack::Timeout and ActiveRecord is wrapping the error awkwardly (see: [Time out an ActiveRecord query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307436/time-out-an-activerecord-query)).

Comment: Yes we are using Rack:Timeout. Let me try this